# CSS: Background-Image not displaying?

Tags: css

I'm having a headache of a time trying to code an image, that's in the same directory as the html and css files. My marker image for bullet points works without a problem, but my background-image for the header doesn't seem to work. I ran it through a css validator and nothing shows up.

EDIT: What I want to accomplish now that I know my image is loading, is to figure out how to overlay my image on top of the h1 element.

HTML5:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
    <link style = "text/css" rel ="stylesheet" href = "pacific.css">
    <title>Pacific Trails Resort</title>
    <meta Charset="utf-8">

</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Pacific Trails Resort</h1>
    </header>

    <nav>
        <a href = "index.html">Home</a>
        &nbsp;
        <a href = "yurts.html">Yurts</a>
        &nbsp;
        <a href = "activities.html">Activities</a>
        &nbsp;
        <a href = "reservations.html">Reservations&nbsp;</a>
    </nav>

    <main>
        <h2>Enjoy Nature In Luxury</h2>

        <img src = "coast.jpg" alt = "Pacific Trails Resort" height = "250" width = "320">

        <p><span class = "resort">Pacific Trails Resort</span> offers a special lodging experience on the California North Coast. 
        Relax in serenity with panoramic views of the Pacific Ocean.</p>

        <ul>
            <li>Private yurts with decks overlooking the ocean</li>
            <li>Activities lodge with fireplace and gift shop</li>
            <li>Nightly fine dining at the Overlook Cafe</li>
            <li>Heated outdoor pool and whirlpool</li>
            <li>Guided hiking tours opf the redwoods</li>
        </ul>

        <div>
            <span class ="resort">Pacific Trails Resort</span>
            <br>
            12010 Pacific trails Road
            <br>
            Zephyr, CA 95555
            <br>
            <br>
            888-555-5555
            <br>
        </div>

        <br>

    </main>

    <footer>
        Copyright &copy; 2016 Pacific Trails Resort
        <br>
        <a href = "mailto:email@address.com">Contact Ian Rosenberg</a>
    </footer>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #666666; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif}

header{ background-image: url('sunset.jpg');
background-position: right; 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
line-height: 400%;
text-indent: 1em;}

h1{background-color: #000033; 
color: #FFFFFF}

nav{background-color: #90C7E3;
font-weight: bold}

nav a{text-decoration: none}

h1{margin-bottom: 0;
font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, serif}

h2{color: #3399CC;
font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, serif}

h3{font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, serif}

ul{list-style-image: url("marker.gif")}

dt{color: #000033}

footer{font-size: 70%;
font-style: italic;
text-align: center;
font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, serif}

.resort{color: #5C7FA3;
font-weight: bold}

#contact{font-size: 90%}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your background is loading its just hidden. The problem you are seeing is that your `H1` element is covering up the entire background because it's display is set to `block` (which is default for `H1` elements.

I am not sure how you want it to display but you have lots of options. You could remove the `background-color` from the `H1` css definition. Which would make the background appear. [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/d7nqmh6e/)

Or you could change the `display` of the `H1` element to `inline-block` or `inline` depending on your requirements. [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/d7nqmh6e/1/)

Finally you could set a `height` of your header class that would still allow the background color of the `H1` to show up. [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/d7nqmh6e/2/)

Again these are a few possibilities still plenty of other ways you could change it. I dont know what your ultimate design goal is so you have to determine the next steps really. But that is the cause of why you cannot see your background.

NOTE: I changed the `H1` class in your CSS for the first two. If you do go this route I suggest that you target that `H1` more precisely because I dont think you would want the same style for the `H1` header applied to other `H1`'s in your page. I did it simply to illustrate how you could fix it.

Comment: Is it possible to have the image on top of the black background? The image fades off to black so it keeps the transition smooth.

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/d7nqmh6e/3/ 
All I did here was set the `background-color` to black and then added a height, and made the image not repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your h1 color style it's overriding the background image style. 
Also your .nav color rule. 
Use firebug or chromes inspect element to go through your styles and see which ones are overriding which. You can turn off and on various styles to see which works.

```css
body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #666666;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
}

header {
  background-image: url(http://fandom.wikia.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Arrowverse.jpg);
  background-position: right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  line-height: 400%;
  text-indent: 1em;
}

h1 {
  /* remove this 
  background-color: #000033; */
  
  color: #FFFFFF
}

nav {
 
  background-color: #90C7E3;

  font-weight: bold
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, serif
}

h2 {
  color: #3399CC;
  font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, serif
}

h3 {
  font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, serif
}

ul {
  list-style-image: url("sqpurple.gif")
}

dt {
  color: #000033
}

footer {
  font-size: 70%;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, serif
}

.resort {
  color: #5C7FA3;
  font-weight: bold
}

#contact {
  font-size: 90%
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Pacific Trails Resort</h1>
</header>

<nav>
  <a href="index.html">Home</a> &nbsp;
  <a href="yurts.html">Yurts</a> &nbsp;
  <a href="activities.html">Activities</a> &nbsp;
  <a href="reservations.html">Reservations&nbsp;</a>
</nav>

<main>
  <h2>Enjoy Nature In Luxury</h2>

  <img src="coast.jpg" alt="Pacific Trails Resort" height="250" width="320">

  <p><span class="resort">Pacific Trails Resort</span> offers a special lodging experience on the California North Coast. Relax in serenity with panoramic views of the Pacific Ocean.</p>

  <ul>
    <li>Private yurts with decks overlooking the ocean</li>
    <li>Activities lodge with fireplace and gift shop</li>
    <li>Nightly fine dining at the Overlook Cafe</li>
    <li>Heated outdoor pool and whirlpool</li>
    <li>Guided hiking tours opf the redwoods</li>
  </ul>

  <div>
    <span class="resort">Pacific Trails Resort</span>
    <br> 12010 Pacific trails Road
    <br> Zephyr, CA 95555
    <br>
    <br> 888-555-5555
    <br>
  </div>

  <br>

</main>

<footer>
  Copyright &copy; 2016 Pacific Trails Resort
  <br>
  <a href="mailto:rosenberg.ian@student.ccm.edu">Contact Ian Rosenberg</a>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong, the exercise I was following did not have a background color or color attribute on the h1 element. To display the image on top of the background I changed my header code to

```
header{background-color: #000033; 
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-position: right; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    line-height: 400%;
    text-indent: 1em;
    background-image: url('sunset.jpg');}
```